# Fazer meu site aparecer na listagem de notícias do Google

Tags: html, google

Possuo um site sobre um determinado assunto. E, quando eu acesso o Google e digito o termo desejado, está lá meu site em uma boa posição.
Porém, eu gostaria que eu meu site fosse listado também na página de notícias do Google.

Pesquisei o termo **teste**, coloquei no *Google News*, e está [aqui a listagem](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=teste&authuser=0&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=gqsBVMesOPHnsASg3ID4Dw&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAA&biw=1304&bih=683&dpr=1).

Minha pergunta é: É o Google que coloca o site lá? Ou é preciso de algumas `metas` no HTML?

Comment: desculpe, respondi pensando que você queria saber como cadastrar para aparecer nas noticias como editor.

Comment: Estava lendo sua resposta. Porém, ela não está mais aqui. Sim, ela estava sendo necessário para a minha pergunta. Foi você que deletou?

Comment: Sim fui eu. Como disse acima, achei que tivesse explicado algo fora de contexto. Se não for útil eu removo para não confundir outras respostas.

Comment: Restaurei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, ela será útil! :D

Comment: Que bom que foi útil (y)

Comment: Obrigado Felipe e @PapaCharlie, ótima pergunta e resposta. E que chovam votos positivos!

Comment: TKS. (y) , ainda bem que a resposta fica guardada quando remove, porque tinha removido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tudo o que você precisa saber está [**aqui no link**](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/?hl=pt-BR#topic=4359866).
Basicamente você cadastra seu site como `editor`.
A doc no link acima possui toda explicação e a doc no link no final é para cadastro de editor.

---

### <sub>Como enviar seu site para inclusão no Google Notícias</sub>

<sub>**Requisitos técnicos**</sub>

> O Google Notícias é compilado por um algoritmo de computador que analisa todos os sites incluídos em nosso sistema. Para que seu conteúdo de notícias seja incluído no Google Notícias, o layout e o formato de seu site devem ser fáceis de ler e decifrar pelo nosso rastreador. Além disso, estabelecemos determinadas restrições para garantir que nosso rastreador inclua somente links para URLs que são realmente artigos de notícias.
>
> Verifique as diretrizes antes de enviar o site para inclusão no Google Notícias. Ao garantir que seu site esteja em conformidade com todos os nossos requisitos técnicos agora, você ajudará a evitar problemas com o site no futuro.

<sub>**Compartilhe seu site conosco**</sub>

> Se você leu todas as informações acima e seu site segue nossas diretrizes para webmasters, bem como as diretrizes gerais, técnicas e qualitativas do Google Notícias, então está pronto para enviar seu site para inclusão. [**Neste link**](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/contact/suggest_content_website)

Comment: Resposta perfeita

Comment: Já inclui alguns sites no Google News, posso dizer que leva algum tempo para ser aprovado, alguns sites mais e outros menos. Se você estiver utilizando Wordpress, existem plugins destinados a gerar sitemaps exclusivos à ferramenta, isto facilita a indexação de forma correta do conteúdo.